# Use of underscore in variable and method names

Tags: java, variables, naming-conventions

I got confused with the (*[naming convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming))*) use of underscore `_` in variable names and method names as their starting letter. For example, `_sampleVariable` and `_getUserContext()`. When should I use it?

Comment: Its simply a coding style to identity `member variables.` But i suggest use `camelCase`, not underscores. [**Oracle PDF for naming conventions**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf)

Comment: go through this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150192/using-underscores-in-java-variables-and-method-names

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the Java [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

> Except for variables, all instance, class, and class constants are in mixed case with a lowercase first letter. Internal words start with capital letters. Variable names should not start with underscore _ or dollar sign $ characters, even though both are allowed.
>
> The names of variables declared class constants and of ANSI constants should be all uppercase with words separated by underscores ("_"). (ANSI constants should be avoided, for ease of debugging.)

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes people use underscores to indicate that their variable or method is private. I do not like this way of doing it. I suggest you to use [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) too.

Comment: Re *"too"*: Do you mean *"[instead](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/instead#Adverb)"*?

Answer (score 7):

Quoting the book *[Clean Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin#Publications)* by [Robert C. Martin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_C._Martin),

> Sometimes it is useful to warn other programmers about certain consequences.
>
> Example
>
> ```
> // Don't run unless you
> // have some time to kill.
> public void _testWithReallyBigFile() {
>     writeLinesToFile(10000000);
>     response.setBody(testFile);
>     response.readyToSend(this);
>     String responseString = output.toString();
>     assertSubString("Content-Length: 1000000000", responseString);
>     assertTrue(bytesSent > 1000000000);
> }
> ```
>
> Nowadays, of course, we’d turn off the test case by using the @Ignore attribute with an appropriate explanatory string. @Ignore("Takes too long to run"). But back in the days before [JUnit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit) 4, putting an underscore in front of the method name was a common convention.

Answer (score 3):

Normally it should not be used, except as a separator in all uppercase constants that are usually final (*allStars* but *ALL_STARS*).

Exactly because normally not expected, the underscore is abundant in generated code. It may also be found in some older code, but this is not the reason to continue using it.

Answer (score 3):

Usually _ is used in variables to represent them as class level private variables.

Comment: Maybe in ____python____