# Spring Data JPA PropertyReferenceException?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I use Spring Data JPA 1.8.0.RELEASE

entity `Attachment` has a property named `relate_id`,

I add a method `findByRelate_id(String rid)` in `Repository`,

but I got a exception:

`Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property relate found for type Attachment!`

I realy need my field name is `relate_id`, not change to `relateId`, And I dont hope write `@Query(...)` by myself.

How to slove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding another `_` to escape it, since it is a reserved character in Spring Data.

```
findByRelate__id(String rid)
```

Check out [this similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475349/4074715).