# Error in query in Jpa with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to get data from the database.But I am getting compile time error.What's wrong with the query and how to solve it?

My domain class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
@Data
public class User {
    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int user_id;
    @Column(name = "type")
    private int type;
}
```

My dao class

```
@Transactional
public interface UserDao extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    User getOneByUserIdAndType(int user_id,int type);
}
```

The stacktrace

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property UserId found for type User!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:235)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:373)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:353)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:87)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:205)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:72)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:369)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:192)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 73 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your repository interface method is named `getOneByUserIdAndType`, Spring will look for a property called `UserId`. It doesn't exist, hence the "No property UserId found for type User!".

You might try an repository interface method named `getOneByUser__IdAndType` (note the double `_`!), or try naming the instance variable userId.

See also [this question on underscores in column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456197/spring-data-jpa-repository-underscore-on-entity-column-name).

Answer (score 3):

getOneByUserIdAndType is a Spring-JPA-Data Query Method (http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods) which comes with some conventions.

UserIdAndType needs the following method signature:

User getOneByUserIdAndType(int userId, int type)

> The query is getOneBy. Query parameters are fields userId will be mapped on field UserId and type on field Type

Now for the PropertyReferenceException. JPA-Data can't map UserId on the Entiy field user_id. You will have to change the Entity fields to this declaration:

```
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int userId;
```

Should still work out for you because JPA still accesses the correct column.