# ElasticSearch SpringBoot+Spring Data: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor found on interface

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to extend ElasticsearchRepository in my project but I am unable to due to the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor
>   found on interface
>   com.example.elasticSearchDemo.Repository.ESDemoRepository to match the
>   given arguments: [class
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.MappingElasticsearchEntityInformation,
>   class
>   org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate].
>   Make sure you implement a constructor taking these

```
//My interface that extends ElasticSearchRepository:

public interface ESDemoRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Data, String>{
    Page<Data> findByEsblog_flow_name(String flow_name, Pageable pageable);

    List<Data> findByEsblog_type(String type);
}

//Data class
@Document(indexName = "logdata", type="doc")
public class Data {
 @Id
 private String id;
 private String esblog_time;
 private String esblog_appl_name;
 private String esblog_host_name;
 private String esblog_iib_name;
 private String esblog_flow_name;
 private String esblog_payload;
 private String esblog_type;
 private Integer esblog_retention;
 private String esblog_tansaction_id;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Data{" +
            "id='" + id + '\'' +
            ", time='" + esblog_time + '\'' +
            ", payload='" + esblog_payload + '\'' +
            ", type='" + esblog_type + '\'' +
            ", retention='" + esblog_retention + '\'' +
            '}';
}
```

}

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = 
ESDemoRepository.class,basePackages="com.example.elasticSearchDemo")
public class ESConfiguration {
@Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
private String EsHost;

@Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
private int EsPort;

@Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
private String EsClusterName;


@Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {

    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName).build();
 return  new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
```

}

```
@Service
public class DemoServiceImpl implements DemoService {



private ESDemoRepository demoRepository;
@Autowired
public void setDemoRepository(ESDemoRepository demoRepository){this.demoRepository=demoRepository;}

private ESDemoDAO esDemoDAO;
@Autowired
public void setEsDemoDAO(ESDemoDAO demoDAO){this.esDemoDAO=demoDAO;}

public String save(Data data) throws Exception {
    return esDemoDAO.esQueryDemo(data);
}

public void delete(Data data) {
    demoRepository.delete(data);
}

public Data findOne(String id) throws Exception {
    return esDemoDAO.esGetQuery(id);
}

public Iterable<Data> findAll() {
    return demoRepository.findAll();
}


public List<Data> findByType(String type) {
    return demoRepository.findByEsblog_type(type);
}
```

Comment: Put you Data class and pom.xml please

Comment: I am using Gradle build. Added Data Class

Comment: Do you have getters and setters and constructor in Data class ? If not try to add them and check

Comment: I do have getters and setters and a constructor in the Data class. I need to use this interface as a bean in my service class , but the bean cannot be created due to the error mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = 
ESDemoRepository.class,basePackages="com.example.elasticSearchDemo")
public class ESConfiguration {
@Value("${elasticsearch.host}")
private String EsHost;

@Value("${elasticsearch.port}")
private int EsPort;

@Value("${elasticsearch.clustername}")
private String EsClusterName;


@Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {

    Settings settings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName).build();
 return  new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() throws Exception {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client());
}
```

Replace:

```
 @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = 
    ESDemoRepository.class,basePackages="com.example.elasticSearchDemo")
```

With this:

```
 @EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages="com.example.elasticSearchDemo")
```

**EDIT**

After this changes there is exception :

```
error:Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property esblog found for type Data!
```

It's because of bad name convention, because the underscore _ is a reserved character in Spring Data. According to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475349/6003541

There are two solutions:

1. Use camel case instead of using underscore.
2. Use double underscore in repository class

Comment: Now i am getting a different error:Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property esblog found for type Data!

Comment: I think your name convension is bad. Try to use camelCase because I'm not sure but Spring probably doesn't recognize your attributes names with _