# Spring Data + Hibernate = Exception :(

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I'm trying to run a training project on Spring. I do:

Application

```
package com.lopamoko.cloudliquid;

import Managers.ProductServiceImpl;
import Service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"Service", "repository"})
@EntityScan("DataModel")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repository")
public class CloudliquidApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(CloudliquidApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("Let's inspect the beans provided by Spring Boot:");

        String[] beanNames = ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        Arrays.sort(beanNames);
        for (String beanName : beanNames) {
            System.out.println(beanName);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ProductService productService() {
        return new ProductServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean filterRegistrationBean() {
        FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
        characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

Configuration:

```
spring.datasource.sqlScriptEncoding=UTF-8
spring.messages.encoding=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
spring.http.encoding.charset=UTF-8
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=hghjghjgjhg
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Entity:

```
package DataModel;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product")
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private long product_id;

    @Column(name = "product_category")
    private String product_category;

    @Column(name = "product_manufacturer")
    private String product_manufacturer;

    @Column(name = "product_name")
    private String product_name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product_list")
    private List<ShopProduct> shops;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product_image")
    private List<Image> image;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "product_information",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "information_id"))
    private List<Information> product_information;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product_rating")
    private List<Rating> product_rating;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product_comment")
    private List<Comment> product_comment;

    public long getProduct_id() {
        return product_id;
    }

    public void setProduct_id(long product_id) {
        this.product_id = product_id;
    }
}
```

Repository(Interface)

```
package repository;

import DataModel.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
@Repository
public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long> {
    List<Product> findByProduct_name(String product_name);
}
```

Service(Interface)

```
package Service;

import DataModel.Product;

import java.util.List;

public interface ProductService {
    List<Product> getAll();
}
```

Service (Class)

```
package Managers;

import DataModel.Product;
import Service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import repository.ProductRepository;

import java.util.List;

public class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Product> getAll() {
        return productRepository.findByProduct_name("Grape");
    }
}
```

And Controller :

```
package com.lopamoko.cloudliquid;

import DTO.Order;
import DTO.ProductInShop.Product;
import DTO.ShopWithProduct.Customer.Customer;
import DTO.ShopWithProduct.Rating;
import DTO.ShopWithProduct.Shop;
import Managers.CustomerManager;
import Managers.OrderManager;
import Managers.ProductManager;
import Managers.ShopManager;
import Service.ProductService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;


    @RequestMapping("/try")
    public List the(){
        return productService.getAll();
    }
}
```

And I get an exception :(((((((

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'productService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'productRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_name(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Product!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1378) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at com.lopamoko.cloudliquid.CloudliquidApplication.main(CloudliquidApplication.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_name(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Product!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1239) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1166) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List repository.ProductRepository.findByProduct_name(java.lang.String)! No property product found for type Product!
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741) ~[spring-beans-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property product found for type Product!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.2.RELEASE.jar:2.1.2.RELEASE]
    ... 55 common frames omitted
```

Help:( Please:((

I would like to note that not in one training video, I was not told to do Bean under the Service, but the IDE requires it from me, maybe I’m doing something wrong?

I'm trying to connect Spring Data, although before that I just used Hibernate, so I still have the hibernate.cfg.xml and HibernateSessionFactory files - Is it possible that the problem is in them and I need to do something with them?

Comment: I don't see getters and setters to product_name in the pojo.

Answer (score 0):

it is because you have "_" in your property name. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456197/spring-data-jpa-repository-underscore-on-entity-column-name) to find your options.

Answer (score 0):

Spring data jpa is not able to find the field in the query.

Change `findByProduct_name` to `findByProductName` and check.