# Spring JpaRepository find entities from attribute using unconventional naming

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

The following used to work in Spring 1.5.10.RELEASE, but does not work in Spring 2.0.7.RELEASE, and I do not know why:

**Entity**

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "locations")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Location {
  // ... unimportant stuff
  @Column(name = "c_locations_id")
  private String cLocationId;
  // ... more unimportant stuff
}
```

**Repository** (aka "The problem")

```java
@Repository
public interface LocationRepository extends JpaRepository<Location, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Location> {
  Location findByCLocationId(String cLocationId);
  List<Location> findAllByOrderByCLocationIdAsc();
}
```

The error I'm getting under Spring 2.0.7.RELEASE for the above code, is

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [CLocationId] on this ManagedType.

I cannot change the name of the attribute due to other circumstances, so I've tried different variations on the methods in the repository:

- `findBycLocationId` - No property orderBycLocationIdAsc found for type Location!
- `findByClocationId` - No property clocationId found for type Location! Did you mean 'CLocationId','cLocationId'?
- `findByCLocationId` - Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [CLocationId] on this ManagedType

What does it want?! I just want to upgrade the framework...

Comment: I have sometime some problems when getter and attribute name doesn't match. But I think it's more an IDE problem (it only underline but that compiles). Good to check.

Comment: Not IDE problem. Maven won't compile...

Answer (score 5):

You can use method name like this:

`Location findByC_Location_Id(String cLocationId);`

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475349/7641626) can be helpful with references

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Query` annotation in your methods [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query).

```
@Query("select l from Location l where l.cLocationId = ?1")
Location findByCLocationId(String cLocationId);

@Query("select l from Location l")
List<Location> findAllByOrderByCLocationIdAsc();
```

Comment: Good workaround, but do I have to? Why did this work in previous version of Spring and not now? Is this type of attribute naming really that unconventional that Spring no longer supports it?

Comment: @ØysteinAmundsen To be honest, I don't know. I saw this https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details but I have not idea.