# Implement Spring Data repository with sort direction

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to implement JPA Repository with sort direction for `private LocalDateTime created_at;`. I tried this:

Service

```
@Override
public Page<PaymentTransactions> findAll(int page, int size) {
    return dao.findAllByCreated_atDesc(PageRequest.of(page, size));
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface PaymentTransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<PaymentTransactions, Integer> {

    Page<PaymentTransactions> findAllByCreated_atDesc(PageRequest of);
}
```

But I get error:

```
 No property created found for type PaymentTransactions!
```

Do you know how I can implement this example properly?

Comment: Yes, but I can't find a solution for this: findAllByCreated_atDesc

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

Service

```
@Override
public Page<PaymentTransactions> findAll(int page, int size) {
    return dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page,size, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "created_at")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, What should I declare into the repository?

Comment: Nothing. JpaRepository extend of  PagingAndSortingRepository .  This is the method that the above example is using Page<T> findAll(Pageable pageable); https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/PagingAndSortingRepository.html

Comment: Is there a way to implement a method into the repository because I want to track everything into one repository?

Comment: Sure. Page<PaymentTransactions> findAllOrderByCreated_atDesc(PageRequest of);

Comment: But you need to escape the _ character. Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456197/spring-data-jpa-repository-underscore-on-entity-column-name

Comment: I gee `No property created found for type PaymentTransactions!` Probably the underscore `_` is the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191876/discussion-between-earandap-and-peter-penzov).

Comment: Do you tried to use findAllByCreatedAtDesc instead of findAllByCreated_atDesc.

Comment: @SmaMa I tried but I get No property desc found for type LocalDateTime!