# MongoDB and Spring: How to correctly query with two fields in one repository query?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, nosql, spring-repositories

I have the following `POJO`:

```
    public class Round {

        private ObjectId _id;

        @NotEmpty
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Accessors(fluent = true)
        @JsonProperty("userId")
        private String userId;

        // rest of fields

}
```

In my Spring boot project I am trying to query my `mongoDB` by userId and _id as follows:

```
@Repository
public interface RoundRepository extends MongoRepository<Round, String> {

    Optional<Round> findByUserIdAnd_id(String userId, ObjectId objectId);

}
```

However when I try to `gradlew bootRun` I now get:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'roundRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property and found for type String! Traversed path: Round.userId.
```

What is the *correct* way to query `MongoDB` with 2 parameters?

Comment: I wonder if the underscore is causing trouble as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23456197/spring-data-jpa-repository-underscore-on-entity-column-name. Can you verify a query for two parameters works if they are named without underscore?

Comment: There's also an error with the creation of bean 'roundRepository'.

Comment: try changing the name of the variable "_id"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use annotation @Document in Round class and the annotation @Id for ID attribute:

```
@Document
public class Round {


        @Id
        private ObjectId _id;

        @NotEmpty
        @Getter
        @Setter
        @Accessors(fluent = true)
        @JsonProperty("userId")
        private String userId;

        // rest of fields

}
```