# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception (Springboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, sts

I have two tables with the following structure:
Course:
|course_id|course_name|
Module
|module_id| duration | module_name | module_type | course_course_id |

Now I want to extract the modules based on the course id:
In SQL the query would be something like this:

```
Select * from modules where course_id = ?
```

This course_id will be passed through a parameter using an API.
I have used JPA to retrieve this. But I get an unsatisfied dependency error each time I run sts.

**Module:**

```
package com.scb.axess.playbook.model;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table (name = "moduless")
public class Module {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "module_id")
    Integer module_id;
    @Column(name = "module_type")
    String module_type;
    @Column(name = "module_name")
    String module_name;
    @Column(name = "duration")
    Integer duration;
    @OneToOne( cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Course course;
    
    public Integer getModule_id() {
        return module_id;
    }

    public void setModule_id(Integer module_id) {
        this.module_id = module_id;
    }

    public String getModule_type() {
        return module_type;
    }

    public void setModule_type(String module_type) {
        this.module_type = module_type;
    }

    public String getModule_name() {
        return module_name;
    }

    public void setModule_name(String module_name) {
        this.module_name = module_name;
    }

    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public Course getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(Course course) {
        this.course = course;
    }
    
}
```

**Course:**

```
package com.scb.axess.playbook.model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
@Entity
@Table (name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer course_id;
    @Column(name = "course_name")
    String course_name;

    public Integer getCourse_id() {
        return course_id;
    }
    public void setCourse_id(Integer course_id) {
        this.course_id = course_id;
    }
    public String getCourse_name() {
        return course_name;
    }
    public void setCourse_name(String course_name) {
        this.course_name = course_name;
    }
}
```

**Module Repository:**

```
package com.scb.axess.playbook.repository;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.scb.axess.playbook.model.Module;

public interface ModuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Module, Integer>{
    public List<Module> findByCourseId(int course_course_id);
}
```

**IModuleService:**

```
package com.scb.axess.playbook.service;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import com.scb.axess.playbook.model.Module;


public interface IModuleService {
     public List<Module> getModulesByCourseId(Integer course_course_id);
}
```

**ModuleServiceImpl:**

```
package com.scb.axess.playbook.serviceimpl;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.scb.axess.playbook.model.Module;
import com.scb.axess.playbook.repository.ModuleRepository;
import com.scb.axess.playbook.service.IModuleService;

@Service
public class ModuleService implements IModuleService{
    @Autowired
    ModuleRepository moduleRepo;

    @Override
    public List<Module> getModulesByCourseId(Integer course_course_id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return moduleRepo.findByCourseId(course_course_id);
    }
```

I get an unsatisfied dependency injection error. Please help and let me know where I am going wrong.
Thank you in advance :)

Error:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-01 18:28:16.078 ERROR 11240 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'moduleController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'moduleRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'moduleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.scb.axess.playbook.repository.ModuleRepository.findByCourseId(int)! No property id found for type Course! Traversed path: Module.course.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1395) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
    at com.scb.axess.playbook.PlaybookApplication.main(PlaybookApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar:2.1.3.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'moduleRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.scb.axess.playbook.repository.ModuleRepository.findByCourseId(int)! No property id found for type Course! Traversed path: Module.course.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:277) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1247) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.scb.axess.playbook.repository.ModuleRepository.findByCourseId(int)! No property id found for type Course! Traversed path: Module.course.
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:82) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:103) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:208) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:566) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:559) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:561) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:551) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:324) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$5(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:297) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:211) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:300) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:119) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1821) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property id found for type Course! Traversed path: Module.course.
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:94) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:382) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:392) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:416) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:358) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.lambda$from$0(PropertyPath.java:311) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:276) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:250) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:251) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.lambda$new$0(PartTree.java:380) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:381) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:96) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:76) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
```

Comment: can you post the whole error message ?

Comment: How does your annotation @EnableJpaRepositories looks like? maybe it is not scanning the right packages.

Comment: Hey @JuanBC I have added the error message above, please check :)

Comment: Traverse path module course object id please check

Answer (score 1):

it's clearly mentioned in following log that spring tried to find that field from the query function name `findByCourseId`, but could not. While writing the query functions, you might get hint from spring itself, try using that.

```java
public List<Module> findByCourseId(int course_course_id);`
```

```
Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.scb.axess.playbook.repository.ModuleRepository.findByCourseId(int)! No property id found for type Course! Traversed path: Module.course.
```

Your field name 'course_id' does not match with the field referred to from the query function. You either need to make change in the query function def name or change the field to 'courseId', with latter the better option.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475349/5342600) you need to modify `findByCourseId` derived query method name.

with this method name spring is trying to find `id` property in `Course` entity,
but in your case the property name is `course_id` and as mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23475349/5342600)
property name with `_` is not working as expected.

So to fix exception which you are getting you have to perform below two steps

- Update `course_id` to `courseId` in `Course` entity
- Update `findByCourseId` to `findAllByCourseCourseId`

Below are the final `Course` and `ModuleRepository` class for which my spring boot application is getting started successfully without any exceptions.

```java
@Entity
@Table (name = "courses")
public class Course {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer courseId;
    @Column(name = "course_name")
    String course_name;

    public Integer getCourse_id() {
        return courseId;
    }
    public void setCourse_id(Integer courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }
    public String getCourse_name() {
        return course_name;
    }
    public void setCourse_name(String course_name) {
        this.course_name = course_name;
    }
}
```

```java
@Repository
public interface ModuleRepository extends JpaRepository<Module, Integer>{
    // public List<Module> findByCourseId(Integer course_course_id);
    public List<Module> findAllByCourseCourseId(Integer courseId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same exception. Solution was found by referring below link.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-unsatisfied-dependency

By using **@ComponentScan** issue was resolved.